# ¿Cómo leer una palabra con la tecla ENTER en JavaScript y HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

He hecho una página y quiero que al pulsar la tecla <kbd>ENTER</kbd> lea la palabra que se ha escrito, pero no se como hacerlo. ¿Alguien tiene alguna solución o idea?.

```html
<body>
   <h1>Title</h1>
   <input type="text" id="guess-input" >
   <button id="guess-button">Try</button>
   <div id='grid'> </div>
   <p id="guesses">
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Asumiré que aún no conoces sobre los eventos y cómo capturar las teclas que presionamos.

---

Podemos hacer lo siguiente:

- Capturar a tu elemento input.
- Detectar al evento que ocurre en el input.
- Cuando escuchamos al evento, detectar si se presionó la tecla <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
- Y cuando detectamos que se presionó, capturamos al valor del input.

Entonces, primero necesitamos saber qué son los eventos y cómo detectarlos.

---

### Los eventos y listeners

Los eventos, son como unas notificaciones que hace el código, como decir que indica de que ocurrió algo en dicho elemento. Estos eventos lo podemos detectar con el método **`addEventListener()`**.

Como dice su [**documentación**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

> ***addEventListener()** Registra un evento a un objeto en específico. El Objeto especifico (en-US) puede ser un simple elemento en un archivo, el mismo documento , una ventana o un XMLHttpRequest. Para registrar más de un eventListener, puedes llamar **addEventListener()** para el mismo elemento pero con diferentes tipos de eventos o parámetros de captura.*

Es decir, con **`addEventListener()`** podemos escuchar los eventos que ocurre en cierto elemento, y una vez ocurra, se ejecutan dichas instrucciones.

---

Entonces, una vez entendemos esto, primero vamos a capturar a tus dos elementos, que son el input y tu botón:

```
let input = document.getElementById("guess-input"); // capturo al input
let button = document.getElementById("guess-button"); // capturo al botón
```

Tu elemento input está almacenado en la variable `input`, y el botón, en la variable `botón`.

---

Y ahora, vamos a agregarles los eventos.

Tu input, necesita ser escuchado cuando presionemos una tecla, que en este caso, es el <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, entonces, necesitaremos a [**`keydown`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event):

```
input.addEventListener("keydown", function() {
  //...
});
```

Aquí básicamente indico que cuando haga el evento `keydown` en el input, es decir, cuando presione una tecla, llame al listener y ejecute la función de adentro.

---

### Detectar las teclas que presionamos

Entonces, lo que necesitamos es capturar a la tecla <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, de la siguiente forma:

```
input.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    console.log(input.value);
  }
});
```

Aquí paso como parámetro `event` a la función, ya que nos vamos a apoyar del evento que ocurre en el `input`. Posteriormente, indico que si la tecla que presioné es <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, cumplo con la condición `if` y capturo el valor del input (con `input.value`).

---

Y por último, con tu botón, hacemos lo siguiente:

```
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log(input.value);
});
```

Que de seguro, ahora se te hará más fácil entender. Indico que si hacemos clic en el botón, llamo al listener y ejecuto la función de adentro, que hace lo mismo, capturar al valor del input con `input.value`.

---

Código completo:

```js
let input = document.getElementById("guess-input");
let button = document.getElementById("guess-button");

input.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    console.log(input.value);
  }
});

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log(input.value);
});
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <input type="text" id="guess-input" >
  <button id="guess-button">Try</button>
  <div id='grid'> </div>
  <p id="guesses">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que por las etiquetas quieres que lo haga en Javascript, para eso necesitas usar alguno de los eventos de teclas.

1. **Keyup** - Tecla ha sido presionada y soltada (lo que hacemos al teclear)
2. **Keydown**   - Tecla ha sido presionada (algo así como lo que haces al usar Ctrl o Alt)
3. **Keypress**  - Lo mismo que keyup pero dentro del elemento que captura el evento.

Ya dependerá de lo que quieras usar, en este ejemplo usaré keypress.

```
let input = document.getElementById("elemento");

input.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    const valor = elemento.value;
    console.log(valor);
  }
});
```

Comment: `keypress` [está obsoleto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event), es preferible usar `keydown`.